# Heroku: How to kill a one-off dyno via Heroku REST API (v3)

Tags: rest, heroku

I was searching for a way to stop/kill a one-off dyno using the REST API v3 of Heroku. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819419/3045181) says that it is possible. However, DELETE-ing a running one-off dyno does nothing in my case, returning `HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted` while the one-off dyno keeps on running.

I've finally found a way to stop a one-off dyno using the legacy API:

```
curl -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/my-app/ps/stop \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 12345678-9123-abcd-1234-123456789abc" \
-d "ps=run.1234"
```

But since it "should" work using the v3, I must be doing something wrong? Stopping a one-off dyno using v3:

```
curl -n -X DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/my-app/dynos/run.1234 \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer 12345678-9123-abcd-1234-123456789abc"
```

The app-name and dyno name are correct since I am able to get its information. Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the Heroku v3 API implementation that has now been fixed. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working with V3 as of today. The V3 responds with "{}" and process continues. With legacy route, the process responded "ok" and terminated with an exit status of 143 (as desired).

Comment: @ZPH I just tried zapping both a web and `heroku run` dyno and it worked in both cases. Please open a support request on help.heroku.com so that we can help you debug this.